# Can we print a file in browser without prompting user to save/open using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, printing, report

In a webpage using jquery can we implement something as given below. Requirement is not to open/prompt user, but automatically send documents to printing queue. But since this is a webpage and we have no much control of clients, is this feasible. Please provide some inputs.

[image: Jquery files print]

Comment: I would not want your webpage to send files to my print queue automatically... a webpage should not be able to do that. i think you have to implement a native client.

Comment: Yep, you can't do that with jQuery if this is the question.